# Angular Bootstrap use custom themes

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I suck at designing websites so I depend on bootstrap and templates. I'm currently trying to create a website with angular. I want to use this template: https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/. It uses Bootstrap with a custom theme. So I'm trying to create this exact same website as a angular website but I'm struggling with the theming.

I have created a recreated the whole index.html and its css files but I couldn't get the Bootstrap theme of the template to work.

So the question is: how to set up custom Bootstrap themes in angular?

Comment: Just import the css, reference the route to the files... There's nothing magical about angular. Frontend is still frontend, regardless of what framework you're using. CSS will still be CSS.

Comment: Sorry I'm still very new to CSS and Angular. The template has a folder "scss" with all the customizations in it. Where/How exactly do I import it to the angular project, so It overwrites the standard Bootstrap styles?

Comment: Maybe you should dive into the basics in html, css and plain javascript before trying out frameworks. Alternatively, read the official documentation. Meanwhile, check this out... https://medium.com/@davembush/adding-css-and-javascript-to-an-angular-cli-project-2b843a8283f3

Comment: I know the basics of html, css and javascript, also this question doesn't have anything to do with it. I also know how to use plain bootstrap. The problem here is that the template I used has customized bootstrap. This is possible with creating sass files that overwrite some variable of bootstrap. I just don't know how to do this in angular.

Comment: ... Bootstrap isn't magic... Its just a bunch of css. SASS like SCSS is just a stylesheet language. There's no magic going on here. just reference the files -.-

Comment: Have you included the dependencies needed in your package.json?
Looks like these are the dependencies needed for 'Grayscale' theme -  **"dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
        "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
        "jquery": "3.3.1",
        "jquery.easing": "^1.4.1"
    },...**
Additionally, have you updated your styles in your angular.json? (**"styles:[]"**..).